# hide site action

Tags: development, permissions

Is there a way set the site actions drop down to be audience specific. Meaning that as the Owner of the site I want to be able to see it, but for other users (viewers, members, etc) I dont want them to see it.  Any ideas?

use the SPSecuritytrimmedControl class that conditionally render the contents/control to the current user based on his/her permission.but my member see site actin,which contribute is sutible for my request?

(the viewer cant see site action but  i want my user with permission add,del,update cant see some list site and cant create page in site ,but in site action have all site content and my member site can see it,please help me.)

Comment: Viewers don't see the Site Actions link by default. Is there any specific reason why you want to hide from users with Contribute access?

Answer (score 6):

The content of the SiteActions page is already security trimmed ([PermissionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.menuitemtemplate.permissionsstring.aspx) combined with [PermissionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.menuitemtemplate.permissionmode.aspx)), so if it is certain actions or new [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465980.aspx) you want to add to the menu, you should change existing permissions or create a new custom action with a permission patter on it.

If you still want to hide the whole SiteActions control from specific users, you could try and place it inside an [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx) web control. I havent tried this for the SiteActions control, but cant see why it shouldnt work. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: I have tried to wrap the site actions declaration in master page into SPSecurityTrimmedControl as described [here](http://www.cwsharepointdesign.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=2). It works.